# RGeo on Ruby under Windows: How to enable GEOS support?

Tags: ruby, windows-7-x64, geos, rgeo

I'm trying to do some spatial operations in Ruby with the `RGeo` gem. Unfortunately, a lot of operations require the `GEOS` library and I can't find any documentation showing how to integrate this in Windows (I am using Windows 7 64bit).

I tried downloading and installing the Windows binaries of `GEOS` from http://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/ and reinstalling the `RGeo` gem via `gem install rgeo -- --with-geos-dir="C:\OSGeo4W64\bin` (<< in this directory there is a file `geos_c.dll`).

Still, using `RGeo::Geos.supported?` returns `false`.

Does anybody know how to solve this?

Comment: Did you get this solved? I am encountering the same problem.

Comment: As far as I remember yes, but this was some time ago and I do not remember all the steps by heart. I think I have some notes how to do it somewhere at my workplace but I cannot access it before start of January. I will pick this up then.

Comment: I would appreciate that. I have a workaround: use postgis to do coordinate transformation on windows, but it is an extra query I would like to avoid.

Comment: Happy new year! As far as I could find out, I could not make it work either back then. However, I think it worked on Windows when I used this gem: https://github.com/dark-panda/ffi-geos
Have you already tried it? To use this ffi stuff after installing (via the gem manager), I did this:
`#Create new factory for direct GEOS access`
`my_factory = RGeo::Geos.factory(:native_interface => :ffi)`
`puts RGeo::Geos.supported? # should return true`

Answer (score 3):

For anyone else looking to do this - here are some tips as to how I got it working.

- install GEOS Windows binaries by following the link from http://trac.osgeo.org/geos/ (I have Ruby 32 bit version, so I went for the 32 bit version)
- you should now be able to find a file geos_c.dll in `C:\OSGeo4W\bin`
- set a Windows environment variable `ENV['GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH']` to be `C:\OSGeo4W\bin`
- check at this point to make sure that ENV variable is there - maybe restart your PC!
- in your Gemfile, add `gem 'ffi-geos'` and `gem 'rgeo'` and bundle install
- in your Ruby file, remember to `require 'ffi-geos'` and `require 'rgeo'` (in that order)
- use `factory = RGeo::Geos.factory(:native_interface => :ffi)` - **not** `RGeo::Cartesian.factory`
- check `RGeo::Geos.supported?` as Dirk said

Comment: If this worked for you, you should mark it as the correct answer